# Fastest way to count ad users in PowerShell?

Tags: performance, powershell, active-directory

I've been looking for the fastest way to count the number of ad users in powershell, aswell as the number of enabled and disabled users, but the queries are very long (~100k users, 1-2 min per query) and my powershell ISE usually crashes after one or two requests (it's for a reporting job)

So my question is how can I optimize these queries :

```
$CountADUsers = (get-aduser –filter * -server $myserver).count.Count
$CountADUsersEnabled = (get-aduser -filter * -server $myserver | where {$_.enabled -eq "True"}).count
$CountADUsersNotEnabled = $CountADUsers - $CountADUsersEnabled
```

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to run Get-AdUser twice. You can save it to variable and just filter it:

```
$allUsers = get-aduser –filter * -server $myserver
$CountADUsers = $allUsers.count
$CountADUsersEnabled = ($allUsers | where {$_.enabled -eq "True"}).count
```

Also, it won't be helpful in that case, but please remember that using `-Filter *` and then `Where-Object` is not very effective as you can just use:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq "True"}
```

Another hint: ISE shouldn't be used for running scripts as it sometimes behave in strange ways (especially when you run out of memory on your machine). You should use `powershell.exe` instead.

Edit: to improve even more you could try to choose only the attributes you need using

```
$t = $allusers |select userprincipalname,enabled
```

And then use `Where-Object` to filter. For comparison:

```
Measure-command {($allusers | where {$_.enabled -eq "True"}).count}
```

took two minutes when

```
Measure-command {($t | where {$_.enabled -eq "True"}).count}
```

took two seconds (but selecting takes about 2 mins so the overall time is more or less the same). However, this strongly depends on the scenario. I'll leave it to you so you can find the best solution for your case. Remember, `Measure-Command` is your very good friend for this!

Comment: thanks man for your advices ! I don't know why I didn't think about that.. helps a lot since the execution is twice as fast.

Also, do you have any idea of why     `$CountADUsereEnabledAndHasMatricule = ($allUsers | where {(($_.extensionAttribute8 -ne "") -and ($_.enabled -eq "True"))}).count`

takes so long ? I want to count the numbers of users with an extensionAtt8, and the execution time is like the same as the get-aduser lol

Comment: I added some comments to my answer. Hope that'll help you optimize even more. If you feel that my answers helped you, please mark it as accepted so others can find it easily. Good luck!